# Nodejs nightmare library button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, nightmare

Hello im trying to click button with nightmare library but that button has not any name so im litte confused.There button(first one is too important to me right now),

```
<button aria-disabled="false" type="button" class="container_t8ohbe-o_O-container_rounded_tid9r1-o_O-container_notBlock_qxxhsy-o_O-container_sizeRegular_9l8x45-o_O-container_1ekx8mc" data-reactid="28"><span class="text_1rqeqtn-o_O-text_sizeRegular_1purd5i-o_O-text_uw47i3" data-reactid="29"><span data-reactid="30">Accept</span></span></button>
```

and this one,

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block"><span>Start</span></button>
```

Even i did try something like that(doesn't matter how ridiculous is) but not worked.

```
.click('class="container_t8ohbe-o_O-container_rounded_tid9r1-o_O-container_notBlock_qxxhsy-o_O-container_sizeRegular_9l8x45-o_O-container_1ekx8mc"')
```

Really want to learn nightmare library but examples are soo few and most of it just include exact same examples.How i can click this button can anyone help ? Also if anyone can provide detailed tutorials about click/type on different examples i am willing to read.

Comment: you can click the button based on css selector where its located

Comment: Copying css selector worked just fine.Thank you, seems like this is answer,      .click('.container_t8ohbe-o_O-container_rounded_tid9r1-o_O-container_notBlock_qxxhsy-o_O-container_sizeRegular_9l8x45-o_O-container_1ekx8mc')

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css path to click the button as long as it is unique to that button. What I like to do is go to developer tools and right click the element then select `copy selector` like this

[image]

Of course make sure to test it with jquery in the console `$('css_selector')` and see if it returns the element you want to click on.

Here's a snippet from one of my nightmarejs projects

```
nightmare
  .goto('https://home.cunyfirst.cuny.edu/oam/Portal_Login1.html')
    .insert('#cf-login', user)
    .insert('#password', pass)
    .click('#login-form > form > input[type="image"]')
```

I also had this issue once where the clicking wasn't working, but [this](https://github.com/Mr0grog/nightmare-real-mouse) library helped me fix that maybe it helps you to. It simulates a *real mouse click* , I'm not sure what that even means, but it works.

Also this is incorrect:

```
.click('class="container_t8ohbe-o_O-container_rounded_tid9r1-o_O-container_notBlock_qxxhsy-o_O-container_sizeRegular_9l8x45-o_O-container_1ekx8mc"')
```

You can test to see if you have a proper selector for the `.click()` by putting in the console like I said earlier heres an example of that:

[image]

I hope this advice helps you!

Comment: I told you EXACTLY what you said.And its worked so confused.I copy css selector and test on console just like you said, and everything is just fine now.Will update topic with answer right now, thank you